# Adding two variables from two different scripts within the same script file (jquery)

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, addition, currency

I am trying to add two different var (values) found in my script, I currently have two different outputs 1 named **div id="item-price"** and another named **div id="vent_total"** ***I would like to know if there is a way to add two different values from two different scripts and then parse those numbers to a Currency function after the final total has been reached.***   Below I have my Jsfiddle attached.  I have attached code that I think might be relevant (my best guess of what I need )it can found in Lines 125-126 of my script code. I have looked on here and haven't found a way to do this.  Possibly my wording is too verbose. I would appreciate any help.  If I need to be more specific, please let me know. I have added notes within my code and have it set up to be tested if anyone would like to look at my functions and html outline.

Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/9pa2kyda/1/

```
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <h1>Products</h1>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    <legend>Options:</legend>
    <label for="product" class="select">Product</label>
            <select id="product" name="product" onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">
            <option id="select" value="None">Please Select Product</option>
            <optgroup label=" Direct Vent Gas Fireplace">
            <option id="DXV35_III" value="#page2">DXV-35 DeepTimber Fire III</option>
            <option id="DXV45_III" value="#page3">DXV-45 DeepTimber Fire III</option>
            <option id="DXV35" value="3">DXV-35 Timber Fire</option>
            <option id="DXV42" value="4">DXV-42</option>
            <option id="FV41" value="5">FV-41</option>
            <option id="FV46" value="6">FV-46</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Direct Gas Inserts">
            <option id="D30" value = "7">D-30</option>
            <option id="D40" value="8">D-40</option>
            <option id="FV33i" value="9">FV33i</option>
            <option id="FV44i" value ="10">FV44i</option>
            </optgroup>
            </select>
    </fieldset>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- 

    DXV-35 DeepTimber Fire III Direct Vent Fireplace Pricing

    -->
    <div data-role="page" id="page2">
      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <h1> Model Types</h1>
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    <legend>Model</legend>
    <label for="1">Model</label>
            <select id="1" class="vars" name="DXV35_III" onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">
            <option value="None" data-price="0">Please Select Model</option>
            <optgroup label="Millennia">
            <option value="#page3" data-price="3799">Millennia Black $3,799</option>
            <option value="2" data-price="3799">Millennia Classic Brass</option>
            <option value="2" data-price="3799">Millennia Full Brass</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Wellington">
            <option value="2" data-price="3999">Wellington</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Andover">
            <option value="2" data-price="4399">Doors & Faceplate</option>

    <!--    This will be added once I know what the following values will be
            <option value="2" data-price="Null">Antique Copper Overlay</option>
            <option value="2" data-price="Null">Gold Overlay</option>
            <option value="2" data-price="Null">Charcoal Overlay</option>
            <option value="2" data-price="Null">Pewter Overlay</option>
    -->

            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Prairie">
            <option value="2" data-price="4399">Doors & Faceplate</option>

    <!--    This will be added once I know what the following values will be
            <option value="2" data-price="Null">Antique Copper Overlay</option>
            <option value="2" data-price="Null">Gold Overlay</option>
            <option value="2" data-price="Null">Charcoal Overlay</option>
            <option value="2" data-price="Null">Pewter Overlay</option>
    -->
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Deerfield">
            <option value="2" data-price="4099">Outside Fit Only</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Victoria">
            <option value="2" data-price="3999">Black</option>
            <option value="2" data-price="4199">Gold</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Tuscany">
            <option value="2" data-price="4099">Black</option>
            <option value="2" data-price="4199">Gold</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Bentley">
            <option value="2" data-price="4499">Black Arch Screen Doors</option>
            <option value="2" data-price="4499">Vintage Iron Arch Screen Doors</option>
            <option value="2" data-price="4850">Gold Arch Screen Doors</option>
            <option value="2" data-price="4699">Antique Copper Arch Screen Doors</option>
            <option value="2" data-price="4699">Gun Metal Arch Screen Doors</option>
            <option value="2" data-price="4699">Swedish Nickel Arch Screen Doors</option>
            </optgroup>
            </select>

            </fieldset>
            </div>
            </div>
        <input type="button" class="button_active" onclick="location.href='#page1';" value="Page 1" />
            </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="page3">
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <h1> Venting</h1>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    <legend>Venting</legend>
    <label for="vent">Venting</label>
            <select id ="vent" class="vars" name="cost_3_qty" onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">
            <option value="#page5" data-price="0">Select Venting</option>
            <optgroup label="Horizontal Venting">
            <option value="#page5" data-price="450">Wall Kit</option>
            <option value="#page5" data-price="475">Corner Kit</option>
            <option value="#page5" data-price="499" >Up & Out Kit-Basement</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label ="Vertical Venting">
            <option value="#page4" data-price="305">Plus 15 per/ft and 45 per/elbow</option>
            </optgroup>
            </select>
            </fieldset>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>



    <!-- 

    DXV-35 DeepTimber Fire III Direct Vent Fireplace Pricing....................END................

    -->

    <div data-role="page" id="page4">
      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <form>
         <h1>Vertical Venting Calculator</h1><br><br>
            <label>Cost Per Foot<input type="text" name="cost_1"  value="15.00"  class="summable" readonly="readonly"/></label>
            <label>QTY of Feet</label><select name="cost_1_qty">
        <option value="0">Please Select Quantity</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="17">17</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="19">19</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="21">21</option>
        <option value="22">22</option>
        <option value="23">23</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="26">26</option>
        <option value="27">27</option>
        <option value="28">28</option>
        <option value="29">29</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="31">31</option>
        <option value="32">32</option>
        <option value="33">33</option>
        <option value="34">34</option>
        <option value="35">35</option>
        <option value="36">36</option>
        <option value="37">37</option>
        <option value="38">38</option>
        <option value="39">39</option>
        <option value="40">40</option>
        <option value="41">41</option>
        <option value="42">42</option>
        <option value="43">43</option>
        <option value="44">44</option>
        <option value="45">45</option>
        <option value="46">46</option>
        <option value="47">47</option>
        <option value="48">48</option>
        <option value="49">49</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
    </select>
                <br>
    <label>Cost Per Elbow:<input type="text" name="cost_2"  value="45.00"  class="summable" readonly="readonly"/></label> 
                    <label>QTY of Elbows: </label><select name="cost_2_qty">
        <option value="0">Please Select Quantity</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
                    </select>

            </form>
            </fieldset>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="page" id="page5">
      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <h1>Installation</h1>
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    <legend>Options</legend>
    <label for="install">Installation</label>
            <select id ="install" class="vars" name="install">
            <option value="#page6" data-price="0" >Select Installation</option>
            <option value="2" data-price="499">Standard Installation</option>
            <option value="2" data-price="900">Complete Installation (Full Tear Out)</option>
            <option value="2" data-price="215">Gas Line Installation Plus 5 dollars per/ft</option>
            <option value="2" data-price="250">Electric(no charge if electric available)</option>
            </select>
            </fieldset>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>


           <div data-role="page" id="page6">
      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <h1>Select Accessories</h1>
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    <legend>Options</legend>
           <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="accessories">Select Accessories</label>
            <select  id="accessories" name="accessories" class="vars" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
              <option>Select Accessories</option>
              <option value="2" data-price="70" >LP Conversion Kit</option>
              <optgroup label="Remote">
              <option value="2" data-price="120">On-Off</option>
              <option value="2" data-price="185">Multifunction </option>
              <option value="2" data-price="350">Burngreen Kit</option>
              </optgroup>
              <optgroup label="Versi-Heat System">
              <option value="2" data-price="450">Heat System</option>
              <option value="2" data-price="200">Installation</option>
              </optgroup>
            </select>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- This is the final page output for final total of all items
        lines 154 thru 166
    -->


    <div data-role="page" id="page0">
      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    <h1>Final Price</h1>
    <div id= "item-price"> </div>
     <div id="vent_total">value from venting calulator page4>
        </div>
         </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!--

            End final page code

    -->

//**************************************************************
//Mobile Transitions Script
//**************************************************************


// (function($) {
//    var methods = {
//        init : function(options) {
//            var settings = {
//                callback: function() {}
//            };
//        
//           if ( options ) {
//                $.extend( settings, options );
//                }
//
//            $(":jqmData(role='page')").each(function() {
//                $(this).bind("swiperight", function() {
//                    var nextPage = parseInt($(this).attr("id").split("page")[1]) - 1;
//                    if (nextPage === -1) 
//                        nextPage = 6;
//                    
//                    $.mobile.changePage("#page"+nextPage, {
//                           transition: "pop",
//                            reverse: false
//                        });
//                   });                        
//
//               $(this).bind("swipeleft", function() {
//                   var nextPage = parseInt($(this).attr("id").split("page")[1]) +1;
//                    if (nextPage === 7) 
//                        nextPage = 0;
//                   
//                    $.mobile.changePage("#page"+nextPage, {
//                        transition: "pop",
//                        reverse: true
//                    });
//                });
//            })
//        }
//        }
//
//    $.fn.initApp = function(method) {
//        if ( methods[method] ) {
//            return methods[method].apply(this, //Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
//       } 
//        else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
//            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
//        } 
//        else {
//            $.error( 'Method ' + method + ' does not exist' );
//        }
//    }
//    })(jQuery);

//$(document).ready(function(){
//    $().initApp();
//});

//**************************************************************
//End Mobile Transitions Script
//**************************************************************



//**************************************************************
// Start Price Calculator Based on "vars" Class
//**************************************************************
var basePrice = 0;

$(".vars").change(function () {
    newPrice = basePrice;

    $('.vars option:selected').each(function () {
        newPrice += $(this).data('price')
    });

    $('#item-price').html(newPrice.toFixed(2));
});

//**************************************************************
// End Price Calculator Based on "vars" Class
//**************************************************************

//**************************************************************
// Start Price Calculator Based on "summable" Class For Venting Calculator 
// for <div data-role="page" id="page4">
//**************************************************************
function doTotal() {
    var total = 0.0;

    $(".summable").each(function (idx, element) {
        $this = $(this);

        var cost = parseFloat($this.val());
        var qty_selector = '[name=' + $this.attr('name') + '_qty' + ']'; // eg: [name=cost_3_qty]
        var qty = parseFloat($(qty_selector).val());
        if (cost && qty) total += cost * qty;
    });

    $("#vent_total").html(total.toFixed(2));
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type=text]").blur(function (e) {
        doTotal();
    })

    $('select').change(function () {
        doTotal();
    });
});

//**************************************************************
// End Price Calculator Based on "summable" Class For Venting Calculator 
// for <div data-role="page" id="page4">
//**************************************************************


//**************************************************************
//BELOW IS THE CODE THAT I THINK I SHOULD USE TO COMBINE THE TWO PRICE OUTPUTS Lines 125 - 126
//**************************************************************

//
//var finish_price = total + newprice 
//$("#MyEdit").html(finish_price.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Narrow down your problem.

Comment: I believe I have in my jsfiddle link.

Comment: This is the code I am trying to use:

"var finish_price = parseInt(total)+ parseInt(newPrice);
$("#MyEdit").val(finish_price.toFixed(2));" 

 I want to add the "total" variable to the "newPrice" variable and place it in the "MyEdit" div id in my html.

Comment: How can I explain this more specifically?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/9pa2kyda/5/

I am halfway there, I changed the location of the script within the last script, since it is only calculated on "selections" it needed to be placed within the 2nd calculating script.

If the user runs through the set up I have got the numbers to add together, I just need to convert the final total to currency.

I have

"var finish_price = newPrice + total

```
    $("#MyEdit").html(finish_price.toFixed(2));
});"
```

Do I just add .currency at the end of the second statement?  If so I have tried that and my script does not work. Is there special syntax when adding Variables togehter?